# Finding $A$ for $Ax=B$ with $x$ and $B$ being matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, inverse-problems, system-identification

I have a simple system which practically follows $Ax=B$, where $x$ is input, $B$ is output and $A$ are parameters.

I have set of $k$ experiments data, so $x$ is actually $N$ by $k$, and $B$ is $M$ by $k$.

I know also that each value in $A$ matrix is positive. My problem is to find $A$ that would give the best fit to experimental data, and fulfill requirement of $A$ being positive.

Is there a proper and established way of solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have $x$ being a matrix so I rename it $X$.

The optimization problem you try to solve is:

\begin{align}
\min_{A} \lvert| AX-B |\rvert_F^2 \;\;\;\;\;s.t.  \,\,A\geq0
\end{align}

We can get the solution by projected gradient descent, i.e. projecting each update on $A$ into the nonnegative orthant via operator $\mathcal{P}_+$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\mathcal{P}_+(A) = \max(A,0)
\end{align}

Where the $\max$ is applied elementwise.

The gradient of the objective function is:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial A}=2(AX-B)X^T
\end{align}

The update on $A$ is then

\begin{align}
A_{k+1}=\mathcal{P}_+\left(A_k-\alpha(A_kX-B)X^T\right)
\end{align}

With $\alpha$ being the step size.